# Very good books about mandelbrot and julia sets.

Tags: reference-request, fractals

I began working on a universal fractal program in which it will be able to generate julia/mandelbrot sets and compare them in different locations side by side and live feedback of changing parameters of the equations.

For my program to be more universal I wanted to get to know lot of theory behind those sets to know what to add to my program in order for it to be universal and without limit (besides processor power).

Can someone recommend very good and thorough books on the mandelbrot and julia sets?

Comment: You can start with Benoit Mandelbrot's own Fractal Geometry of Nature.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pictures_of_Julia_and_Mandelbrot_Sets is free and focusses on visualisation rather than other theoretical aspects

Comment: The wiki book takes lot of thinking to unferstand because there are no examples of code or detailed explanations.

Comment: You can see the following lectures from the official channel in YouTube **Petra Bonfert-Taylor**, *Week2Lecture3: Iteration of quadratic polynomials, Julia sets*, *Week2Lecture4: How to find Julia sets*, and  *Week2Lecture5: The Mandelbrot set*. I found these lectures in YouTube in the past, and now I read your post and I am asking myself if it is you are looking about fractals. Are videos of the more high quality, and I hope that it is a good introduction for you. Good luck.